# C# Error using Base64 convert on hash

Tags: c#, ms-access, base64, sha256

Basically I am getting a saved hash (converted to base64) from an access database and comparing it (after converting it back) with another and should return true if they match, but for some reason it returns false. There is data in the database. I think the problem occurs when the hash is converted back from base64. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
private static bool MatchSHA(byte[] p1, byte[] p2)
    {
        bool result = false;
        if (p1 != null && p2 != null)
        {
            if (p1.Length == p2.Length)
            {
                result = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < p1.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (p1[i] != p2[i])
                    {
                        result = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


private static byte[] GetSHA(string userID, string password)
    {
        SHA256CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        return sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userID + password));
    }
public void RunTest()
    {
        string userId = "test";
        string password = "Password";
        string enteredPassword = "Password";
        var hashedPassword = GetSHA(userId, password);
        string encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedPassword);
        try
        {
            string connString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|Password.accdb");
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [UserId] = @UserId";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
            OleDbDataReader dbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dbReader.Read())
            {
               var compareHash = Convert.FromBase64String(dbReader["Password"].ToString());
               errorLabel.Text = "Hash from DB: " + dbReader["Password"].ToString();

                 if (MatchSHA(compareHash, GetSHA(userId, enteredPassword)))
                 {
                     loginLabel.Text = "EnteredPassword. True";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     loginLabel.Text = "EnteredPassword. False";
                 }

            }
            conn.Close();

        }
        catch (OleDbException obe)
        {
            errorLabel.Text = obe.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: SHA1 is not secure.  Use bcrypt or PBKDFv2.  You also need salt.

Comment: @SLaks I am not using SHA1 and i am salting. Read the code.

Comment: Have you tried using these functions (the GetSHA and MatchSHA functions) while leaving the database out of it? if they work then, then it might be a problem with the database somehow.

Comment: What is value of `errorLabel.Text`? Side note: your code calls some `GetSHA1` and `GetSHA`, but sample have only `GetSHA` version. Make sure to show all relevant code... And as SLaks said - drop SHA1. Use at least SHA256.

Comment: @Cheesy - have *you* read your code? `var hashedPassword = GetSHA1(userId, password)`? Or you are lying in function names?

Comment: @Cheesy: You're right; I misread.  But SHA2 is still too fast; you need iterative hashing like PBKDFv2 or specially-slow algorithms like bcrypt.

Comment: It looks like he's using SHA256 (`SHA256CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();`) but I still don't see salt...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes; his function name is lying.  (and it's declared with a different name, too)

Comment: @Tim, the method do work without the db

Comment: @Cheesy: And, a user ID has nowhere near enough entropy to serve asa good salt.  Plus, salts should be unique per _password_, not per user, so that an attacker cannot tell whether a user reset a password to an older value.

Comment: @Cheesy - ok. So can you find some way to verify the bytes coming out of the DB are the same as the ones that went in? it seems like that is where the problem is, right?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I changed the name of the function after copying it here, i must of missed one

Comment: @SLaks I know i am just doing this for testing

Comment: @tim When this runs  errorLabel.Text = "Hash from DB: " + dbReader["Password"].ToString(); it prints the value thats in the DB

Comment: And is that value the same value that went INTO the db (not just what is stored in there)? I guess my point is... Compare the value before the DB to the value after the DB. Either they are different (and something with the db is changing it) or your Match code is wrong. There's only two options :)

Comment: @tim Yes its the same as the one entered.  I will double check the code

Comment: Probably not the problem, but you really shouldn't be using `Encoding.ASCII`. Use `Encoding.UTF8` to get the bytes from the User Id and Password. Otherwise, your users won't be able to use any characters other than the ASCII set, which probably wouldn't make your non-US users very happy.